# How to hide the keyboard using ‘done’ button Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4

I was wondering how can I hide the keyboard using the ‘done’ button when I’m entering in a UITextField.

Thank you,

Unknown.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use below code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate

  // set delegate in didLoad
     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       textField.delegate = self
     }


   // MARK: - Search Method
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the delegate on the text field and implement this method. Should do the trick.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but as I am a beginner at Swift 4, how do I « set the delegate on the textfield » ? Thank you.

Comment: So I can't be sure of the context, but I'm assuming this is in a UIViewController and you're using Swift. All you do is declare that the view controller conforms to UITextFieldDelegate (e.g. class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate). Then somewhere (probably viewDidLoad), you add the line - myTextField.delegate = self. Alternatively, you can do that directly in the Storyboard or XIB. Lastly, you add that method to the view controller. If all that worked, then the keyboard should go away whenever the Done button is tapped.

Comment: If the text field is set up in a storyboard you can just control-drag from the text field onto the view controller's icon at the top of the view controller scene (after making sure the view controller conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, as you said) and connect the view controller as the text field's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

According to me if you want to handle all the textFields in the application.
You can simply use the [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) for handling all the stuff.

Just Insert the following single line of code in appDelegate's didFinishLaunching after installing the appropriate pods.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    return true
}
```

And Done button will automatically managed in app.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate on the text field and implement this method. Should do the trick.

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```